# approach to use layers in css and make image show i the front of menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu like

[image]

but would like to get a resultlike this

[image]

So far I have this:

```
<div id="bottomnav">
    <ul>
        <li>

<a  href="#" target="_blank" title="lamp">
    <img class="swing" src="http://site.cheetos.com.br/static/masterbrand/img/cap1-poste.png" width=250 height=350 style="z-index: 10"  /> 
</a>            


        </li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I added z-index, but I am doing it wrong, What can it be done to put the image above the menu?
please take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5Vv5/28/)

Comment: Try `ul li a {position: absolute; z-index: 10; left: 0; bottom: 0;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aligning Multiple Images In a Fixed Footer**

You want something like this:

```
#bottomnav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: no-repeat url(http://eurekavi.com/barraroja.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#bottomnav ul {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    list-style: none;
}

#bottomnav ul li {
    width: 25%;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    outline: 1px solid yellow;
}

#bottomnav li img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

where you HTML looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a  href="#" target="_blank" title="lamp"><img ...  /> </a>            
    </li>
    <li>
       <a  href="#" target="_blank" title="lamp"><img ...  /> </a>            
    </li>
    <li>
       <a  href="#" target="_blank" title="lamp"><img ...  /> </a>            
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/s5GNA/

**Some Explanation**

Your `bottomnav` parent container is absolutely positioned at the bottom, that is fine.

For `ul` and `li`, inherit the height so as to take the guess work out of where the bottom of the elements are (when you float the content, the heights will collapse otherwise).

For `li`, you must set the position to relative and float them left.

Finally, absolutely position the images left and bottom to 0.

If you can, make your images all of the same dimensions and adjust the lamp bases so that they have a common baseline, otherwise, you need to tweak the `bottom: {n}px` setting for each image where '{n}' is some number to be found by trial and error.

Comment: Thank you,  I have added more images but they seem not to be at the same y position, do you know what could be done?  please check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/s5GNA/